# Text size consistancy cross browser / device?

Tags: accessibility, usability, text-size

Assuming I make a website's text sizing with em, how much will the sizing vary cross browser and device? Im actually redesigning a site and if I make the text larger with firebug some of the layouts screw up, how much of an issue is this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way to keep text size consistent across browsers is to use pixels rather than ems. This defeats older browsers text resizing options, but that's a decision you have to make.

Comment: Ive heard the main benefit of ems is browsers can resize them, but do people actually use this feature? I often resize sites with firefox but it resizes the whole thing, so the text layout doesn't change relative to the rest of the page.

Comment: Also, say I set pixel sizing for text on a form or menu that could screw up if the text was resized, will some devices override this? Or will they just ignore all the css in which case the page would work ok.

Comment: Zoom is the more commonly used feature now and it's wired up to the control+mousescroll as well, and you can still resize text if modern browsers (e.g. FF4) but in older versions of IE, changing the text size had no effect if you specified the font-size properties in pixels.

Comment: So to play it safe is it necessary to assume some people will resize the text (not zoom)? Thanks

Comment: I was talking to a guy with low vision recently who uses the text resize feature in preference to zoom: the problem with zoom is that he then needs to do lots of panning back and worth because the width of the page is now larger - whereas with text-only zoom, the page with stays generally the same, so he only has to scroll downwards as he reads.